# IntelliJ plugin option to appear on right clicking on file in project pane

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins

I have written an IntelliJ plugin which is currently tied to GenerateGroup. Following is a snippet from plugin.xml:

```
  <action id="generateinnerbuilder" class="className" text="Plugin Text"
          description="Plugin Description">
     <add-to-group group-id="GenerateGroup" anchor="last"/>
  </action>
```

I want to make sure that the plugin invoke option is displayed when I right click on the Java file from project pane but I can't seem to find the correct "group-id" for it.
Appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: `GenerateGroup` seems to be the correct ID.

Comment: It is, for a generator plugin. I want it to appear on file right click.

Comment: I see, please try `CodeMenu`.

Comment: Tried, it appears in the "Code" menu, on the top taskbar.

Comment: What about `EditorLangPopupMenu`?

Comment: I don't know where it went now, but it's not in right-click option on the file.

Comment: Last try: `EditorPopupMenu`

Comment: Nope, that didn't work either. Anything else I can try?

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work, [see the source code for this menu definition](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-resources/src/idea/PlatformActions.xml#L570).

Comment: CutCopyPasteGroup did the trick! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"CutCopyPasteGroup" did the trick.

snippet:

add-to-group group-id="CutCopyPasteGroup" anchor="last"